# Why does the limit $\frac{xy}{y-x^3}$ when $(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)$ equal $0$?

Tags: limits

After I've tried a lot of paths, always, I've ended up with $0$.

Accordingly the wolfram alpha, it is correct.

However, I don't know how to prove it using, for example, the *squeezing method*.

What is it the best approach to deal with it?

I thank for any help.

Comment: I'm not so sure it does exist - what happens when you aproach along the curve $y=x^3$ ?

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=xy%2F%28x-y%5E3%29+at+%280%2C0%29

Comment: Accordingly with [wolfram alpha](http://goo.gl/YnmOxo), it does

Comment: It is not defined when $y=x^3$.

Comment: @AJStas, you inverted the order: it is $y-x^3$ and not $x-y^3$

Comment: @copper.hat, so what could be wrong with [this solution](http://goo.gl/YnmOxo). Is there some typo in the entry?

Comment: @HellonCanellaMachado: I don't need to look at WA to see that it is not defined! WA is far from perfect.

Comment: Try the path $y=x^3+x^5$.

Comment: @copper.hat Analyzing the various answers given here, your statement have shown true. Thank you for the contribution.

Comment: Hmm. ${}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a reasonable argument for staying away from $y=x^3$. However, let $y=x^3+x^4$. The limit along that path is $1$. You can play with that idea and get various values.

Answer (score 0):

Take $x_n = {1 \over n}$ and $y_n = {1 \over n^3-n^2}$.

Note that $x_n \to 0, y_n \to 0$.

Now note that ${x_n y_n \over y_n - x_n^3} = n$.

Note that $\lim_n n = \infty$.

Alternatively, pick some $c$ and look at the path $(x, {cx^3 \over c-x})$, and
note that the limit along this path is $c$ (adjust appropriately to avoid $x=c$).

Answer (score 0):

Simple fact: If you have continuous functions $f(x,y),g(x,y)$ in the open first quadrant $U$, with $f$ nonzero in $U$ and $g = 0$ only along a curve $\gamma$ in $U$ that approaches $(0,0),$ then as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$ within $U \setminus \gamma,$
$\lim f(x,y)/g(x,y)$ does not exist. Proof: Take any point on $\gamma.$ Then $f/g$ blows up at that point. It follows that $f/g$ is unbounded in every $D((0,0),r)\cap (U \setminus \gamma),$ so the limit cannot exist. (In the present problem, $f(x,y) = xy, g(x,y) = y-x^3, \gamma = (x,x^3).$)